# Phrasing a long string to a 2d array PHP

Tags: php, string, explode, multidimensional-array, split

I have a long string say "123~456!!!789~012!!!345~678!!!901~234!!!567~890!!!1234~5678". I have used to types of delimiter in this string **~** and **!!!** . Can anyone suggest me an efficient way to explode(split) this string to a 2d array.
Example:

```
$txt = "123~456!!!789~012!!!345~678!!!901~234!!!567~890!!!1234~5678".
```

The 2D array after exploding/splitting.

```
array[0][0] = 123 ; array[0][1] = 456 ;
array[1][0] = 789 ; array[1][1] = 012 ; 
array[2][0] = 345 ; array[2][1] = 678 ;
array[3][0] = 901 ; array[3][1] = 234;
array[4][0] = 567 ; array[4][1] = 890;
array[5][0] = 1234 ; array[5][1] = 5678;
```

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all it takes:

```
foreach(explode("!!!",$txt) AS $key => $subarray) {
    $array[$key] = explode("~",$subarray);
}
print_r($array);
```

Quick and efficient, and you'll get your two-dimensional array.

See: http://3v4l.org/2fmdn

Answer (score 0):

You could use `preg_match_all()` using `PREG_SET_ORDER` and then map each item to eliminate the zero index:

```
$txt = "123~456!!!789~012!!!345~678!!!901~234!!!567~890!!!1234~5678";

if (preg_match_all('/(\d+)~(\d+)/', $txt, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
        $res = array_map(function($item) {
                return array_slice($item, 1);
        }, $matches);
        print_r($res);
}
```

Alternatively, use a double `explode()`:

```
$res = array_map(function($item) {
    return explode('~', $item, 2);
}, explode('!!!', $txt));
print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$txt = "123~456!!!789~012!!!345~678!!!901~234!!!567~890!!!1234~5678".
$firstSplit = explode("!!!",$txt);
$newArray = array();


for($i=0;$i<sizeof($firstSplit);$i++){
  $secondSplit = explode("~",$firstSplit[$i]);
  for($j=0;$j<sizeof($secondSplit);$j++){
    $newArray[$i][] = $secondSplit[$j];
 }
}
```

I think something like that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `preg_split()` function.

```
$txt = "123~456!!!789~012!!!345~678!!!901~234!!!567~890!!!1234~5678";
$array = preg_split ('/!!!|~/', $txt);
print_r($array);

Output: 
Array ( [0] => 123 [1] => 456 [2] => 789 [3] => 012 [4] => 345 [5] => 678 [6] => 901 [7] => 234 [8] => 567 [9] => 890 [10] => 1234 [11] => 5678 )
```